# How to draw a tree containg leaf and node like image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am to write some jquery so that i can draw it like attached image.
All will be static.[image]

Comment: why 1 negative, please justify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great JQuery pluggin called [Org Chart](http://th3silverlining.com/2011/12/01/jquery-org-chart-a-plugin-for-visualising-data-in-a-tree-like-structure/) with full documentation. It should help you to get started.

[Responsive demo](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html)